# SQL Error in a insert query where there is a select * from

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to run this query but the sql server show this error:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

This is my query:

```
insert into gdo_funcionario (TIPDOC, CEDULA, NOMFUN, CODFUN, CODDEP,
                             EMAIL, CODCARGO, ACTIVO, ID_TER) 
VALUES (4, 123456789, 'Name Name Name Name', 'Usuario',
        (select coddep from gdo_grl_dependencias where codigo='11'),
        'xxxxx@xxxx.com',
        (select idcargo from mp_grl_cargo where nombre ='Cargo Cargo Cargo'),
        1, (SELECT * FROM GDO_TERCERO WHERE NUMTER =1234566778899));
```

I'm not an expert in DB so I hope someone can help me. Thanks

Comment: select * in the last sub-select is not allowed. (Sub-select may not return more than 1 column.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have subqueries in your `INSERT`. That's allowed if they return only a single value. So you either have to fix them to return only one or force it by using `TOP 1`:

```
INSERT INTO gdo_funcionario 
            (TIPDOC, 
             CEDULA, 
             NOMFUN, 
             CODFUN, 
             CODDEP, 
             EMAIL, 
             CODCARGO, 
             ACTIVO, 
             ID_TER) 
VALUES     (4, 
            123456789, 
            'Name Name Name Name', 
            'Usuario', 
            (SELECT TOP 1 coddep 
             FROM   gdo_grl_dependencias 
             WHERE  codigo = '11'), 
            'xxxxx@xxxx.com', 
            (SELECT TOP 1 idcargo 
             FROM   mp_grl_cargo 
             WHERE  nombre = 'Cargo Cargo Cargo'), 
            1, 
            (SELECT TOP 1 ID_TER
             FROM   GDO_TERCERO 
             WHERE  NUMTER = 1234566778899));
```

Comment: What if for example `SELECT TOP 1 idcargo 
             FROM   mp_grl_cargo 
             WHERE  nombre = 'Cargo Cargo Cargo'` return more than one row, will you randomly insert value?

Comment: @lad2025: yes, it will select the first row's `idcargo`-value. That's why i've mentioned that OP should fix the subqueries to return the correct row. I don't know the logic. But maybe the `TOP 1` is correct because he doesn't care or all have the same values. He can control which row is used in TOP 1 by adding other conditions to the  `WHERE`-clause or by adding a `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 1):

One of those `SELECT` statements is returning more than one value.  If you add a `TOP 1` with an `ORDER BY`, you should be fine.